# How do I delete the messages a discord bot sent after a time interval? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot using python that will send certain messages every few seconds. So it doesn't clutter the channel, I want it to delete the messages it last sent in the beggining of the while loop, to replace the messages with the new ones.

I don't know how to do this and any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Bot Started.")
    global bot_status
    bot_status = "running"
    while bot_status == "running":
        if bot_status == "stopped":
            break

        time.sleep(10)

        #delete
        #delete
        #delete

        await ctx.send("test")
        await ctx.send("test")
        await ctx.send("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send) function has a parameter named `delete_after`. You can use it to delete the messages after a specific time. Also, instead of using strings, you can use booleans.

```py
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Bot Started.")
    global bot_status
    bot_status = True
    while bot_status == True:
        if bot_status == False:
            break
        await ctx.send("test", delete_after=11)
        await ctx.send("test", delete_after=11)
        await ctx.send("test", delete_after=11)
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

Or, you can use [`Message.delete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete). For that, you have to assign the sent messages to variables.

```py
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Bot Started.")
    global bot_status
    bot_status = True
    while bot_status == True:
        if bot_status == False:
            break
        msg1 = await ctx.send("test")
        msg2 = await ctx.send("test")
        msg3 = await ctx.send("test")
        await asycnio.sleep(10)
        await msg1.delete()
        await msg2.delete()
        await msg3.delete()
```

Comment: Using time.sleep in an asynchronous function will stop the bot from working, as it's a blocking function. Instead, refer to asyncio's [`asyncio.sleep(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) coroutine.

Comment: Right, I forgot that.